# how can I open an activity and also pass a context object in android

Tags: android

I am facing some kind of problem and I can't figure out why. When I call the function "mapFound" by clicking a button, something bad happens. But I think it looks like fine.

```
package com.fva_001.flashvsarrow.com.fva_001;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MapFound extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.find_map);
}
// when I click this button, error happens
public void mapFound(View view){
    MapFoundDialog dialog = new MapFoundDialog(getApplicationContext());
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

And here is my MapFoundDialog class

```
package com.fva_001.flashvsarrow.com.fva_001;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MapFoundDialog extends Dialog {

public Context c;
public Button yes, no;

public MapFoundDialog(Context a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map_found);

// Here I want to open a new Activity, I think it has some problem too
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_map_open);
    no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ButtonClick(getContext(), v);
            Intent entireMapIntent = new Intent(c, EntireMap.class);
            c.startActivity(entireMapIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What __bad happens__?

Comment: You can access context from next activity, so why you need pass context ?

Comment: please post Stack trace so to make it more clear.

Comment: But passing an entire activity is a serious issue and also, sometimes the activity loads and sometimes not...

Answer (score 0):

Please check by giving context of Activity instead of application context. See the below code,

```
package com.fva_001.flashvsarrow.com.fva_001;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MapFound extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.find_map);
    }
    // when I click this button, error happens
    public void mapFound(View view){
      MapFoundDialog dialog = new MapFoundDialog(MapFound.this);
      dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems with context .

```
public MapFoundDialog(Context a) {
super(a);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.c = a;
}
```

you can try this

```
 public void mapFound(View view){
  MapFoundDialog dialog = new MapFoundDialog(MapFound.this);
  dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But every first time when I open the activity, it doesn't work but later, yah...it's alright...

Comment: Call that method in onResume() and not a way to say thanks either upvote or accept answer if it help.